# Binding UserControl property to Window property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm struggling with some binding issues.
I have a UserControl with a TextBlock. The text of the TextBlock is bound to a property.
When using the UserControl in a window and setting the property with some text, everything works as expected. But when I bind that property to another property in the window, nothing happens.
This is an example that shows the issue:

UserControl xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestBinding.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeText}"/>
```

UserControl code:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SomeText", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata("Control Default Text"));

    public string SomeText
    {
        get { return (string)this.GetValue(SomeTextProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(SomeTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public UserControl1()
    {
        this.DataContext = this;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Window xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TestBinding.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestBinding"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <local:UserControl1 Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <local:UserControl1 Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" SomeText="Another Text" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding SomeText}"/>
    <local:UserControl1 Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" SomeText="{Binding SomeText}" />
</Grid>
```

Window code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SomeText", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata("Window Default Text"));

    public string SomeText
    {
        get { return (string)this.GetValue(SomeTextProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(SomeTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.DataContext = this;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

What I expect to see in the bottom right corner is "Window Default Text" but what I get is "Control Default Text".

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when you set `UserControl1.SomeText` to text because then binding context does not matter but when you use binding and do

```
public UserControl1()
{
    this.DataContext = this;
    ....
}
```

you overwrite `DataContext` that would normally be there through inheritance and change context for `UserControl1` bindings. Remove above line and change XAML as follows:

```
<UserControl ... x:Name="myUserControl">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=myUserControl, Path=SomeText}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have explicitly set `DataContext` to itself in UserControl constructor.

```
public UserControl1()
{
    this.DataContext = this;  <-- HERE

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

So ***by default binding engine will search for all properties in its DataContext*** i.e. within itself. Hence, could not find `MainWindow.SomeText` property.

You have to explicitly resolve it like this:

```
<local:UserControl1 Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                    SomeText="{Binding DataContext.SomeText,
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                        AncestorType=Window}}" />
```

---

**OR**

Don't set DataContext to itself in UserControl constructor and change binding of TextBlock in UserControl to this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeText,
               RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                    AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

This way it will automatically inherit windows dataContext.